# Why can not I choose an aliase in sql database?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

In the following code, I want to give the round column (321.8751,3) the decimal alias, but it gives an error even when I put it in a **double quote** unless I change its name to "decimal number" or decimal_number. Why?

```
select round(321.8751,3) as decimal,ename,hiredate
from emp
where job=upper('manager') or job=upper('president');
```

error message:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Comment: Your code works if you use a quoted identifier for the alias `decimal`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0ae4f5ba64171e2b6c27e262e600c4d7) Are you sure the subsequent errors (after you fix that part) are coming from the same place or are you using `decimal` unquoted elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, `decimal` is reserved, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words, i.e. needs to be delimited as `"decimal"`.

Comment: Why `job=upper('manager')` and not `job='MANAGER'`? Or perhaps you want `upper(job)='MANAGER'`?

Comment: @MT0 It worked right now without changing anything! Only
I added a double quote that I had already added and it did not work. I think the servers had a problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`decimal` is most likely a reserved keyword, that's why it's asking to quote it, it'd be better if you chose a different name for that column.

Comment: If it is in double quote, will it still be reserved?

Comment: `round(321.8751,3)` is a function taking two arguments `321.8751` and `3`. It is not taking a single argument `321.8751,3`.

Comment: @MT0 Well, it has taken 2 arguments for me too!I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @amz It was a comment on this answer as it states "`321.8751,3` is a formatted number, `3218751,3` will work." which is wrong as `321.8751,3` is not a formatted number but is two separate arguments and `round(3218751,3)` is not the same as `round(321.8751,3)`.

Comment: I would remove this "321.8751,3 is a formatted number, 3218751,3 will work." from the answer. The part about decimal being a keyword is the correct answer. I would offer an upvote, if it were not for the first sentence.